# MVC: How to run some custom dependant actions before/after main action

Tags: php, model-view-controller, front-controller

The following code is in my `FrontController`. The run method should call a controller action which belongs to a given url. For example `http://localhost/admin/index` should point to `AdminController` and `indexAction`.

This works already, but what's the best way to call additional controller actions, for example a action for building a navigation of my site or a aside box (is not in the main section of the site) with some information. A navigation is needed at every request, so this would be no problem to implement, but when I have to call some actions which depends on the main action, how to structure this?

My first approach was to call other controller actions  in two methods like `runBeforeMainController` or `runAfterMainController`. A global config holds the info for main controllers which sub controller (actions) needs to be called before or after the main controllers call.

My second approach was to think about a hook / event system. But I didn't come to good theoretical solutions. Do you have some tips or suggestions for this approach?

```
// in FrontController
public function run() {
    $strController = static::getControllerNameFromUrl();
    $strAction = static::getActionNameFromUrl();
    // call actions before main controller
    $this->template->main = $this->callMainControllerAction($strController, $strAction);
    // call actions after main controller
}
```

Comment: Commented before teresko removes the mvc tag.

Comment: Why do not inherit the corresponding action from some generic action (i.e. inherit certain controller from some base controller) which will do the stuff?

Comment: @AlmaDo Then I would have many different BaseControllers. I think thats not a good architecture.

Comment: Why? Do one base controller in which you'll do stuff with your navigation.

Comment: @AlmaDo Yeah you're right, but when I have different sub actions to call at different main actions? And how do I put the template output of the sub actions to the right position in the main template then?

Comment: Not sure what's the problem. You mean actions with same name in different controllers that need to be customized differently? Then certainly solution is - put that custom code in that actions (because that logic belongs to them). And if not (i.e. customization is same for both of them) - then create parent action in parent controller and put that customization there

Comment: No, I mean I have several controllers: `NavigationController`, `AdminController`, `UserController` and so on. They all inherit from an abstract controller with some base functionality. When I call for example `AdminController->doSomethingAction` I want to execute `NavigationController->buildMenuAction` before.

Comment: Still not able to get why idea with base controller won't fit that requirement

Comment: you can try a pre-dispatch hook: Register a plugin class in your front controller and put your code for menu navigation in `preDispatch()` method of that class.

Answer (score 1):

I think HMVC is what you're looking for. The H stands for hierarchical. Basically you are using multiple mvc-constructs. Your site gets more modular and one request may result in different actions.

Afaik there are already some PHP frameworks using this approach.